# Extremely small Object is pixelated

Tags: rendering, scale

I've had to scale down an object (tree) by an extreme scale in order to achieve a seamless fractal loop. The smaller object appears pixilated/deformed when in the rendered view, yet is the exact same object as the larger one, just at a different scale. I have included the scale to the right if needed. Have a look at the difference:

[image: 01]

[image: 02]

[image: 03]

[image: 04]

I'm not too sure how to wrap my head around solving it.
Big thanks if we manage to.